# How to find the external link of a bookmark in a PDF file in Java using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I managed to find all bookmarks that have destinations to certain pages in the same PDF file using PDOutlineitem. However, some bookmarks lead to completely different files. I called getAction() and getDestination() on PDOutlineitem, but they all returned null. Any idea on how to find a bookmark's external link to another PDF file?

Comment: Please link to your pdf... or have a look at it with PDFDebugger and post a screenshot of the outline item.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I actually solved it... now I'm just having trouble finding a PDF example with bookmarks referencing to a webpage or an email link

Comment: Run the AddAnnotations.java example in the source code download, this creates a PDF with a link.